# Why doesn't he go by "Dr. Freeze"?

Tags: dc, batman, mr-freeze

I was inspired to ask this question by [this](http://textsfromsuperheroes.com/tagged/Mr.-Freeze):

[image: Texts from Superheroes]

Victor Fries is a doctor. However, he goes by *Mr.* Freeze. Have any of the comics explained why he choose to do this?

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d4/Batman121_mr_zero.jpg

Comment: He decided to start using the title "Doctor", but he got... cold feet.

Comment: None of his diplomas say "Freeze" so he couldn't prove it if challenged.

Comment: Have any of the comics demonstrated that he chose the name? Out of universe, he was created as Mr. Zero, and was renamed, and given the first hints of backstory, years later.

Comment: Perhaps he is a surgeon and an Anglophile - so follows the British method where surgeons are called Mr.

Comment: “Please, ‘Doctor’ Freeze is my father. Call me Jeremy.”

Comment: It's his secret identity. If anyone suspects him, he can say, "Hey, I'm Doctor Fries, he's Mister Freeze. Totally different names, see?"

Answer (score 9):

Probably because Mr. Freeze as we know him was popularized in *Batman: The Animated Series*, and TAS took most of its villains directly from the Adam West *Batman* series.

Following Mr. Freeze's origin story back to Adam West, we get the following:

> Dr. Schivel was a criminal mastermind residing in Gotham City until he met his match in Batman. During an attempted arrest, Batman accidentally spilled some 'instant freeze' solution on Schivel, freezing his molecular structure making him a being of pure cold. Thus, the criminal 'Mr. Freeze' was born.
>
> <sub>Source: [Batman Wikia.](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._Freeze_(Otto_Preminger))</sub>

In this version of his origin, even though he is addressed as a doctor, him being a doctor has very little to do with his gimmick as opposed to our recent TAS-inspired Mr. Freeze who devoted his entire life to cryogenics research. Thus, there was probably no reason to make "doctor" a part of his criminal title originally and the TAS writers didn't want to alter his name.

Comment: Dr Jekyll and Mr. Hyde

Answer (score 2):

I don't think an in-universe explanation has ever been given.

Out-of-universe, the character's name and origin are a product of writing choices spanning decades and what we're left with is something that doesn't make as much sense as it would if it were all thought up at once.

In his original appearance, Batman #121 in 1959, he was known as Mr. Zero and had no backstory. He was mostly a throwaway character with an ice gun. (Source: [Heart of Ice Interview](http://www.worldsfinestonline.com/WF/heartofice/interview/))

In the 1966 Batman TV show, he was renamed Mr. Freeze and was referred to as Dr. Schivel but the origin was never fleshed out as was just as much a throwaway character as ever. (Source: [DC Comics Database](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Schivel_(Batman_1966_TV_Series)))

Freeze didn't get the origin we all commonly think of until the 1992 episode of *Batman: The Animated Series* titled "Heart of Ice". He was given the identity of Victor Fries, a cryogenics scientist who places his terminally ill wife, Nora, into cryogenic stasis in hopes of eventually finding a cure. (Source: [Heart of Ice Interview](http://www.worldsfinestonline.com/WF/heartofice/interview/))

The name "Mr. Freeze" makes more sense when you understand the evolution of the character even though it seems strange when you stand it side-by-side with his modern origin.